# How to type guard TypeScript type if instanceof only supports classes?

Tags: typescript, filter, types, casting, typeguards

Need to type guard but `instanceof` doesn't work with TypeScript `type`s:

```js
type Letter = 'A' | 'B';
const isLetter = (c: any): c is Letter => c instanceof Letter; // Error: 'Letter' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

// Expected usage: Filter via type guard.
isLetter('a'); // Should output true
'foo bar'.split('').filter(c => isLetter(c)); // Should output 'a'
```

Haven't found similar questions but `instanceof` works with classes:

```js
class Car {}
const isCar = (c: any): c is Car => c instanceof Car; // No error
isCar('a'); // false
```

If `instanceof` only works with classes, what is it's equivalent for `type`, & how can we type guard using a TypeScript `type`?

Comment: See [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMhzAgJygXigcgIIagH0wCEMBuAKAGMB7AOwGdgoBLOuBZNKACgoC4oAhjRABKfhWZ1Y8RClQA+KBNTpsuPAWWri5MgHo9UAKIAPSBUQATKAFc6AgOYR+AMSYAbWVABuTAVFBIKAcbASRLADpKWjoqdwgI9yoHLhY2WS4MAQwRERIoAygAZQALKht3a3LgMBtGYCQbCGj6OISklIwAMyoqKAAjMIwIujB3JmBMnIiujwzlRTSZZB5cvILDUvLKqGraxiyMIA). Does it answer your question? If not, what am I missing? (Characters  are case-sensitive, so your test expectations are incorrect)

Comment: good solution, I was looking at this & found we can check against a list of the values but is there a way to do this without repeating the union types?

Comment: Yep, check this one [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBAGwKYxkgTlOBeOBtAcgEECAaOAgIQIF04BDLcaGAbmBgE8AHJOAGRRp0OOF15gAZoiEYoeCAFcAtgCMMNds1hwAllEGoMogBQgAXAwicAlJZB6sh4TgB8Mo5gB0uiCASKACZIUGY27MCRAPRRcACiAB68IGiBcIpQ9ADmSJYAYroILgBuuvRiPHxZivTogV6gkFBgyF4IYFkm+s4YJgT0BDbhcDFwAMoAFmCKCGnTMNyK8DDoikiN0C1IbR19kmBgcKq1BF5Q3Ai6MH2DXpKFwmZujj3oYUOsI7GT07Nw84t4P0CEA)

Comment: wow, I didn't realize we could pass the values into the type, great solution. Please post it as an answer & I'll accept it to help others :)

Comment: When you create a class in TS you also automatically create a type of the same name, but types don't persist at runtime. The keyword `typeof` also exists both at the type level and at runtime as you have discovered, but it doesn't do the same thing in both contexts. These are exceptions rather than the rule. When you use typeof at the type level, you can only infer the type of values which can be statically known.

Comment: I haven't tested `typeof` at compile- vs run- time as the confusion was around `instanceof` & usage with `type` but good suggestion, & good point on `type` created with class - I didn't realize that happened

Comment: Yes I was anticipating a bit. I take it you come from a language other than JS and there may be confusions and frustrations regarding what is type level and what is runtime. Some choices like the typeof keyword are a little questionable

Comment: yes, still learning TS' type space, the confusions are usually with using type in value space, any resources on this & type recursion would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TS types only exist in the compilation phase, not in runtime.

In a user-defined type guard it is your duty to implement appropriate checks. The check will vary depending on the type of input and output - selecting between a few alternatives is simpler than asserting the shape of completely unknown object.

For your type Letter (union of 'A' and 'B') it is enough to check whether input is A or input is B

```ts
const isLetter = (c: any): c is Letter => c == 'A' || c == 'B';
```

If your union has more members and you dont want to repeat them in union and in type guard:

```ts
const letters = ['A', 'B'] as const;
type Letter = typeof letters[number];
const isLetter = (c: any): c is Letter => letters.includes(c);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBAGwKYxkgTlOBeOBtAcgEECAaOAgIQIF04BDLcaGAbmBgE8AHJOAGRRp0OOF15gAZoiEYoeCAFcAtgCMMNds1hwAllEGoMogBQgAXAwicAlJZB6sh4TgB8Mo5gB0uiCASKACZIUGY27MCRAPRRcACiAB68IGiBcIpQ9ADmSJYAYroILgBuuvRiPHxZivTogV6gkFBgyF4IYFkm+s4YJgT0BDbhcDFwAMoAFmCKCGnTMNyK8DDoikiN0C1IbR19kmBgcKq1BF5Q3Ai6MH2DXpKFwmZujj3oYUOsI7GT07Nw84t4P0CEA)

Note: Classes are preserved at runtime (via prototype chain) - which is why you can use instanceof operator with classes.

Comment: the explanation on classes existing at runtime was useful in clarifying why `instanceof` worked with classes. Nice solution of array type to avoid to repeated union strings. Thanks for explaining :)

Answer (score 0):

Found a possible but not ideal solution for type guarding a union strings type is to check against a list of the union strings:

```js
const isLetter = (c: any): c is Letter => ['A', 'B'].includes(c);
isLetter('A'); // true
isLetter('a'); // false
```

Not ideal since the union strings are duplicated in the type & the type guard - open to better solutions

Answer (score 0):

Typescript is a compile-time technology. You are trying to use a Typescript type, which is a concept that only exists during compile time, to construct a runtime check (a check that is to be executed in the JavaScript runtime).

By the time the emitted JavaScript gets executed, the TypeScript notions are already long gone (that is, they are already stripped away).

Hence you should not try to implement this check in the body of the function as a runtime check, using the TypeScript interface/type. This will not work.

To implement a compile-time check, on the other hand, is just a matter of replacing `any` for the parameter type with the TypeScript type `Letter`.

This code might help clarify the matter:

```
type Letter = 'A' | 'B';
// compile-time check is implemented by assigning the parameter 'c'
// to a TypeScript type
const shouldBeLetter = (c: Letter) => {
  // implement a runtime check using JavaScript, not TypeScript
  if (c !== 'A' && c !== 'B') throw "c should be either 'A' or 'B'";
  /* rest of the function */
}

// example of a statament that fails at compile time
// error: Argument of type '"D"' is not assignable to parameter of 
//        type 'Letter'. (2345)
shouldBeLetter('C');

// example of a statement that won't fail at compile time, but will
// need a runtime test
let couldBeC : Letter = 'ABC'[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)] as Letter;
shouldBeLetter(couldBeC);
```

PS: The provision of compile-time types in TypeScript, which are stripped away from the emitted (the compiled) JavaScript files, creates two distinct contexts within of a TypeScript code file:

1. the *expression context* (the parts to be emitted later as JavaScript)
2. the *type context* (the TypeScript parts which will be removed)

In the so-called, *type context*, it is possible to repurpose some of JavaScript's keywords to have a different meaning in TypeScript. An example is the `typeof` keyword: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html

In JavaScript, `typeof` is a unary operator that returns a string at runtime, that string correlates with the type of the value/variable following it.

... when used in TypeScript, in the *type context*, it gives the TypeScript-equivalent type of the value/variable following it.

In the same way, expression-like notions such as `letters[number]` can be used in the *type context* in TypeScript to derive type information from actual variables, as explained here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html

Both points are very neatly utilized in the other answer by @Lesiak when reusing the enumerated-type array between the *expression context* and the *type context* within the code.

Comment: `(c: Letter): c is Letter` doesn't make a lot of sense. If you already know something is `Letter`, you don't need a type guard. I have the same kind of grief about your other example. Maybe rephrase what you were attempting to say.

Comment: Haha. Yes I see what you are saying.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, @geoffrey I tried to rephrase to make my message clearer

Comment: good point on TypeScript notions not existing at runtime, I was aware of this but was trying to find a way to assert the type at runtime, which I realize is only possible with the values. I didn't use `c: Letter: c is Letter` due to asserting unknown values as @geoffrey mentioned

Comment: Yes, I improved my answer and added to it to acknowledge the genius use of `typeof` by @Lesiak